# Is it possible to have a select in a custom control's basic settings

Tags: orbeon

Is it possible to put a dropdown list in a custom control's Basic Settings? I have tried the below in custom control, but the select doesn't show up. The [page on metadata](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/metadata.html#control-metadata-for-the-edit-control-details-dialog) only mentions `xf:input`s, but I would to be able to put a select in there (to restrict possible values)

```
<template>
    <ap:binput inputtype="email" min="2">
        <xf:label ref=""/>
        <xf:hint ref=""/>
        <xf:help ref=""/>
        <xf:alert ref=""/>
    </ap:binput>
</template>
<control-details>
    <xf:input ref="@min" type="xf:decimal">
        <xf:label lang="en">Minimum Value</xf:label>
        <xf:hint />
    </xf:input>
    <xf:select1 ref="@inputtype">
        <xf:label lang="en">Input Type</xf:label>
        <xf:hint lang="en">HTML5 Input Type</xf:hint>
        <xf:item>
            <xf:label lang="en">Third choice</xf:label>
            <xf:value>3</xf:value>
        </xf:item>
        <xf:item>
            <xf:label lang="en">Third choice</xf:label>
            <xf:value>2</xf:value>
        </xf:item>
    </xf:select1>
</control-details>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the documentation correctly: currently only `<xf:input>` controls are supported inside `<fb:control-details>`. Following this questions, I've created [an RFE for this](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2612).

You can see where this is done if you look at the source of `dialog-control-details.xbl`, and should you want to support one more control there, it should be reasonably easy to update that file for that purpose.

Comment: And we have now implemented this, so in 4.11 you'll be able to use `<xf:select1>` and other controls.

Comment: Awesome! Cheers guys.